# $\mathbb C P^n - p \simeq \mathbb C P^{n-1}$ if $p \in \text {int} (D^{2n}).$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space, deformation-theory, retraction

> Let $p \in \text {int} (D^{2n}).$ Then show that $\mathbb C P^n - p \simeq \mathbb C P^{n-1}.$

I know that $\mathbb C P^n \approx \mathbb CP^{n-1} \sqcup_q D^{2n},$ where $q : S^{2n-1} \longrightarrow \mathbb C P^{n-1} \approx S^{2n-1}/S^1$ that identifies points on $S^{2n-1}$ which are $S^1$ multiples of each other. So if we take $p \in \text {int} (D^{2n})$ then clearly $\mathbb C P^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbb C P^n - p$ and $D^{2n} - p \simeq S^{2n-1}.$ From here can it be concluded that $\mathbb C P^n - p \simeq \mathbb C P^{n-1}\ $?

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Recall the (biholomorphic) automorphism group $PGL(n,\mathbb{C})$ of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ acts transitively so you can just move your $p$ to the centre of $D^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Manifolds are homogenous, meaning that there is a homeomorphism taking any one point to any other. Therefore, we might as well assume $p$ is the center of $D^{2n}$. If we remove a point from the center of a disk, we may radially scale to deformation retract onto the boundary sphere. We may extend this by the identity everywhere to conclude $\mathbb{C}P^n -p$ deformation retracts onto $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$.

Comment: I am really sorry to say you that I am not familiar with manifolds. Is there any easier argument using quotient maps, homeomorphisms etc to conclude the same? Thanks.

Comment: @Phibetakappa What homogeneity gets you is that you can pick any point $p$ and remove it and have the result be true. You specifically only ask for the case when $p$ lies in the interior of the disk you attach. So you should just find a deformation retraction from the disk with p removed to the boundary.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my question. But how will it induce the desired deformation retraction?

Comment: I think the homogeneity of manifolds is a "heavy gun" in the present case. It suffices to observe that $D^{2n} \setminus \{\text{interior point}\}$ strongly deformation retracts onto $\partial D^{2n}$. This can be proved *directly*.